# ¿Qué normas sigue Microsoft para traducir sus aplicaciones?

Tags: windows

Cuando Microsoft (o para el fin cualquier otra empresa) crea una aplicación que desean localizar a otros lenguajes y países, ¿de dónde toman los términos para que, digamos, un CHECKBOX se llame siempre CASILLA DE VERIFICACIÓN y no termine cambiando a CASILLA DE OPCIONES, BOTÓN de VERIFICACIÓN o lo que sea?

Supongo que debe existir algún documento publicado para la estandarización de interfaces en la que se establecen normas sobre cuándo usar mayúsculas y minúsculas, los nombres de los elementos gráficos y demás.

¿Alguna idea o enlace que pudiera llevarme a estos documentos? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una guía de estilo que se puede descargar desde https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/StyleGuides